# Where can I find bonds time series?

Tags: fixed-income, data, bond, historical-data, cds

I want to study dependence and correlation between bonds and CDS. I have already found [a large CDS database of time series there: www.datagrapple.com](http://www.datagrapple.com)

I am looking for such a similar database (with an important intersection on the single names) for bonds. Somebody is aware of such free-access database?